# Asp.Net MVC Application Design pattern for a mid-size application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

So I hear a lot about Repository pattern. But it seems a-lot work to do. 
For a mid-size application does the hard work worth. Can you tell me the advantages in bullet points.

Also where can i find easiest tutorials on repository pattern with asp.net mvc. Is there any scoffolding exist.

Also i need suggestion on other patterns if possible with samples projects.

Need to say, i wouldn't create a test project for my web project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MVC Scaffolding.  It will set up your application and CRUD operations.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/